# Trouble understanding the node.js walker

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Im having trouble understanding how the signature/header of the [node.js walker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walker) works. I understand, that a walker can iterate through a folder and you can set filters etc. But i dont really understand how the signature of the `.on` works.

As an example:

```
Walker('/etc/')
.filterDir(function(dir, stat) {
  if (dir === '/etc/pam.d') {
    console.warn('Skipping /etc/pam.d and children')
    return false
  }
  return true
})
.on('entry', function(entry, stat) {
  console.log('Got entry: ' + entry)
})
.on('dir', function(dir, stat) {
  console.log('Got directory: ' + dir)
})
```

At the `.on` signatures,
 -What do the `'dir/entry'` parts do?

**EDIT**
I specifically mean what `.on(**this part**, function(entry, stat))` {...} *This part* is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The walker, I assume, asynchronously accesses files starting from your defined folder, `/etc/`, and as it access files and folders as it's walking, it fires events.

Every time it accesses any element, whether its a file or a folder or whatever, I would imagine it fires the `'entry'` event.

Every time it accesses a file, it fires the `'file'` event.

Every time it accesses a directory, it fires the `'dir'` event.

The first parameter to `.on` defines what events you want to register a callback to, and the second one is the callback itself, which takes as its first argument the element in question, or the path to it.

Answer (score 2):

`'dir'`, `'file'`, `'symlink'`, `'blockDevice'` and so on are simply different things that act like files in the UNIX "everything is a file" design philosophy. For instance, you can list the devices connected to the system such as hard drives by running `ls /dev/`

The events in walker are simply filtered by "file type". `'entry'` will trigger the callback function on every filesystem object, `'file'` will only trigger for files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Those are function parameters. They define variable names that get values when the function is called.

```js
const myFunction = function(dir, stat) {
  console.log('Got directory: ' + dir)
};


myFunction("Foo", "Bar");
```

It is just that the function is called by *code you did not write yourself*.

Comment: I want to know what the part _before_ the function is doing. See the edit